# Scrapy: Can't define bot name anymore in scrapy 2.1.0

Tags: scrapy

I have a scrapy 2.1 project running where I have under the root directory two folders. My intention is to have 2 projects with seperate bots and settings in addition to a global setting.

Now I tried to define project names, so I used the export command. Unfortunatelly this somehow changed the bot name to "scrapybot" and it is not possible to rename it again:

```
merlin@192-143-0-9 spider1 % export SCRAPY_PROJECT=bid      
merlin@192-143-0-9 spider1 % scrapy settings --get BOT_NAME 
scrapybot
```

The project is within a git repo and doing a git status, it does show no changes at all. The spider list is empty now due to the renamed project.

This looks like a bug to me, so my main question is:

1. How can I rename my bot back to it`s original name "bid" where all spiders are located?

Once I have it back running, the second question which led me to the current problem is:

2. How can I specify two different projects under one root directory with their own spiders and settings?

Comment: I got it back after a reboot as the only option was that is was saved in RAM. However the original problem stil remains.

Answer (score 1):

- It's normal `git status` doesn't show any difference. You're just setting an environment variable. `scrapy settings` will read the values from the settings.py file, so depending on which project folder you're under, it will either give you 'bid' or 'scrapybot'
- The following structure allows you to have multiple scrapy projects under 1 root directory, each with its own settings & spiders:

```
root/
    scrapy.cfg
    bid/
        __init__.py
        items.py
        middlewares.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            bidspider.py
    scrapybot/
        __init__.py
        items.py
        middlewares.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            scrapybotspider.py
```

Comment: Interesting. I created a folder simply by adding it through the file system. Guess this is not enough, since the file __init__.py is missing within the second project. How do I create the second project under the same root?

Comment: It's enough to just follow the directory structure as outlined, and to make sure scrapy.cfg is updated (as explained in the docs here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#sharing-the-root-directory-between-projects)

Comment: I understand that each project needs middlewares, pipelines, items, spiders. But how can those two projects share e.g. the middleware? This is the whole reason why they are under the same root. From what I understand now this is not possible since if I want to deploy one project it would be incomplete without the other one. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to share middlewares etc between spiders, I think you need to put these spiders indeed under the same project.

Comment: OK, thank you for the info. I am now seperating the spiders into seperate projects under seperate root directories.